# Add more properties within select of LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a huge entity (Record) with around 20 fields. One of them is StatusID, which is mapped to Status table. I want to pull the status and show in the UI for each record. For this I can

1. create a custom model, write a LINQ with join and map all required attributes into custom model
2. Add additional attribute in Record model, after fetching the records, loop each record, fetch the Status and update

I am not comfortable with either. Since it includes lot of overhead, either performance or memory / maintenance. Is there a better way? I am looking for something like

```
from x in db.Records inner join y in db.Status on x.StatusID equals y.StatusID select (x, y.Status) as x
```

Comment: You should go with option 1, but can you elaborate on overhead, performance, memory, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a foreign key is set up in your database, you could use the LINQ `Include` operator to populate your `Status` navigation property for each `Record` entity that you retrieve:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

// ...

var records = db.Records.Include(x => x.Status);
```

Then, in your UI, you can bind to `Status.Name`.

Comment: return (from x in db.Records.Include("Status") select x).ToList();  // this works.

Comment: @KrishnaSarma: You can condense that to `return db.Records.Include("Status").ToList();`